# Which 40K army is this?

Tags: warhammer-40k

A friend of mine has recently acquired some models from 40K that look like space marines/chaos marines.

Can anyone identify which army their from?

[image]

Comment: I see Space Marines mixed in with Chaos Space Marines and a Dark Eldar ship.

Comment: I think this could help someone else if more information about how to identify the pieces is presented.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ship in the back is a Dark Eldar Raider.  The big robot thing behind it is a Chaos Dreadnought.  The infantry also appear to be Chaos Space Marines.

Comment: Yes, all infantry looks like chaos space marines. Those chaos backpacks are very characteristic. Also some infantry clearly have Khorne helmets with the U like shape (like foremost row, second to last infantry unit, red helmet). My guess is that motorbike ones are also chaos based on the backpacks too.